# Monitoring Regions fails when stop and start MonitoringForRegion - iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager, clregion

My App should be able to Monitor different Regions. It should be also possible to "Edit" monitored Regions. I know thats only possible to start and stop Region-Monitoring. But that is my Problem. I've implement the following Workflow:

1. Search monitored Regions in `CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions` using `Identifier` Property of `CLCircularRegion`
2. Stop `CLCircularRegion` using `CLLocationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion`
3. Start Monitoring new ("edited") `CLCircularRegion` using `CLLocationManager.startMonitoringForRegion`
4. Check State with `CLLocationManager.requestStateForRegion`

But there is no new `CLCircularRegion` started.

`CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions` is 0.

It seems that stop and start MonitoringForRegion needs to have a delay between.
Cause when i set a Breakpoint between Point 2. and 3. it works.

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all monitored region and again to add region to monitor which you required.

Comment: Okay, do you know why this behaves like that ? I mean i have e.g. 10 Regions monitored but i want only one of them remove/stop and add/start again.

Comment: no idea for that, i was facing same before and able to fix it by this way only.

Answer (score 0):

Both `startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region` and `stopMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region` are performed asynchronously. Try to request the status later.

[image]